# OAUTH2 Python Facebook Login

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am new to web programming- I've recently been familiarizing myself with the webapp2 framework.  I'm trying to start building a website, and would like users to login to the site with Facebook and I'll need access to their friends list.  I've been trying to find a way to do this- I found out about OAUTH2, and I think this may be a way to do this.  All the tutorials for python and OAUTH2 that I've found have been using the google API, I'm not sure if it's any different, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Does anyone have sample code they can post that uses OAUTH2 (or anything else) to get users to sign in through Facebook?  Or any good resources that can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app needs to authorize users with Facebook, since there's where the resources you need are (e.g. friend lists).

This is a classic use of OAuth2 and you don't have a way around it, because FB implements this protocol.

My suggestion is that you look at the Google sample and then adjust it for FB API. The important changes are:

1. The endpoint URLs (e.g. `authorize`, `token` and `user profile`
2. The **scopes** that define the extent of permissions you are requesting (e.g. list of friends)
3. The **user profile** (e.g. the information returned by FB on a user: name, e-mail, etc)

This is [a *very* simple sample](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-python) that does this in Python. It was meant to run in Google App Engine. The only caveat is that it uses our own library to encapsulate the flow. But you can use it to study how [the basic protocol](https://docs.auth0.com/protocols#1) works. Run [the live demo](http://auth0-py-sample.appspot.com/) and turn on dev tools on your browser to see the network activity.

You will notice that OAuth2 is a rather simple protocol, using simple HTTP requests.